# How do automatically resize an NSPopover with auto layout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autolayout, appkit, nspopover

I currently have an NSPopover subclass which sets it content view controller to a custom NSViewController meant to represent a tab view:

```
    self.popover.contentViewController = tabViewController;
    self.popover.animates = YES;
```

I'm rolling my own "tab view controller" because I've heard that NSTabViewController doesn't play well with animations.  I'd like to use auto layout so I don't think I want to mess around with the popover's contentSize property.  When I change tabs the popover correctly changes its size, however, it doesn't animate the change.  Furthermore, I have a cross-fade animation that occurs when the tab view switches and the popover doesn't resize until after the animation finishes.

First, I'd like to figure out how to get the popover resize to animate and then I'll worry about getting the animation in sync.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, Did you find any solution for it ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?